# I renamed a package and my app won't launch

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been following [this](http://www.kilobolt.com/create-an-android-game-from-scratch-or-port-your-existing-game.html) tutorial to create an android game. I downloaded the skeleton he provided but changed one of my packages from `robotgame` to `highst`. Whenever I try and deploy the application with the example code to my device I get the following error.

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]         cmp=com.ronyo.robotgame/com.ronyo.highst.Loader }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.ronyo.robotgame/com.ronyo.highst.Loader} does not exist.
```

I've searched for an instance of `robotgame` in my project and I can't find an instance of it. The tutorial above is created using Eclipse and I'm porting it to Android Studio. I'm wondering if I've overlooked something when switching IDEs?

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.ronyo.highst"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
       android:icon="@drawable/icon"
       android:label="Loader" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Loader"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="Loader"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.inten.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete the folders .idea and .gradle then click button "Sync project with gradle files"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the package wasn't updated everywhere.  Have you changed anything in the manifest?

In the AndroidManifest.xml file, in the `<manifest` tag, there should be a package attribute.  That needs to be updated to match your new package name, `com.ronyo.highst`.

Check out the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Answer (score 0):

don't change it directly , It'll not update all the references, use this

> right click on project > Android tools > Rename application package

[image]

Comment: The tool tip for renaming in Android Studio says `Rename the selected symbol and correct all references`.

Comment: try to del the project from IDE and get again in IDE, then compile